# What is difference between Access Modifiers and Access Specifiers

Tags: java

1. I saw so many sites, I get information like that.

   **Access Specifiers:**
    
        1.public,
        2.private,
        3.protected, and
        4.default.
    **Access Modifiers:**

        1.final,
        2.static,
        3.Synchronization,
        4.abstract and
        5.transient
2. In other sites they told us both are same.
3. In some other sites

   **Access Modifiers will be:**

        1.public,
        2.private,
        3.protected, and
        4.default.

I am totally confused about these things. 
Can any one explain about this,please?

Comment: http://way2java.com/oops-concepts/specifiers-modifiers/access-specifier-vs-access-modifier-in-java/

Comment: yes but i saw in different site like http://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers .. so that i confused

Comment: There are lots of pages around the internet claiming lots of things. Regarding Java, there is only one [authoritative source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). See for example [class modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1), [field modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1) and [method modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3). Note how even Annotations are considered being modifiers…

Comment: javatpoint, roseindia etc., are not authoritative sources or normative references. Only the JLS is that. You can't cite any other source against what it says in the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

The sites you have found are all spouting A grade drivel, and I have devoted non-trivial amounts of my life to extirpating them.

The term 'access specifier' does not appear in the Java Language Specification. That's all you really need to know. Random Internet sites, including Wikipedia and this one, can say whatever they like, but unless they agree with the JLS they are wrong.

Of the keywords you have mentioned, 1,2,3, and 4 are access modifiers, as they modify access to the item, and the rest are variously storage classes, Serialization keywords, synchronization keywords, or non-existent ('Synchronization').